# SQL query on many-to-many relation

Tags: sql

I have the following schema:

```
Photo [id, name]

Gallery [id, name]

PhotoGallery [photo_id, gallery_id]
```

Each photo can belong to many galleries.
I need to make an SQL (MySQL) query that will allow me to display all distinct photos (grouped by id) which do not belong to some galleries.
For example we have following data:

```
Photo
------
1 bunny
2 rabbit
3 eagle

Gallery
-----
1 bunnies
2 rabbits
3 birds

PhotoGallery
-----
1 1
1 2
2 2
3 3
```

I want to select all photos which do not belong to gallery 'bunnies'.

The result should be:

2 rabbit

Any suggestions? The query should also be fast because I have about 10,000,000 photos in Database. And gallery can contain 300,000 photos.

Comment: Could you show the SQL statement(s) you've tried so far that are not working for you?  Please see the [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page here on Stack Overflow, especially the "Do your homework" section.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM photos
WHERE photoID NOT IN (select photoid from photogalleries where galleryid=1)
```

Comment: Will this query perform well on database with 10,000,000 photos?

Comment: I doubt it. Unless you have a gallery with 9,999,900 photos in it, you're going to get an enormous result set back.

Comment: Here's an article related to performance - http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
      p.*
FROM 
      photos p LEFT OUTER JOIN PhotoGallery pg on p.id = pg.photoid
WHERE 
      pg.photoid IS NULL AND pg.galleryid = 1
```